# How do I define the order of a form's Controls array?

Tags: delphi

When I have a form, I can access components via `TForm.Controls[]`. Is it possible to change a component's index in that array from IDE? I tried to edit form as text, and change the order there, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Why do you want to change the order of the components?

Comment: You can access only components that are controls via `Controls[]`.

Comment: You really do need to explain why you asked the question to get the best help

Comment: I would like to serialize big form (lots of Edits,Combos,Checkboxes and Radios) and save it to database. Most of the elements should be in right order. Adding tags is too much work, as there may be alot of them. I do understand it is not the best approach, but would be the quickest one.

Comment: Why does the order matter? Perhaps you should design your program so that you don't use gui controls as your data storage.

Comment: It is a poll, dynamically generated. Wanted to be able to determinate which answer is which. I am saving labels too, but would be good to be able to cast answer id aswell without defining tags or anything.

Answer (score 6):

Changing the order of the controls within the DFM will work just fine.

**Update** However, that only really affects the order of the `Controls[]` list at Form creation when the DFM is streamed.  Once the Form is up and running, the order of the `Controls[]` list changes dynamically if the Z-order of any of the controls changes over time, such as from calls to `TControl.BringToFront()` or `TControl.SendToBack()`.  The order will also change if you change the `Parent` of any of the controls in the list.

So you are not really guaranteed any particular ordering at any given time.

Comment: It will also change if you change the Parent of a control.